# Select Left(columnA,2) or right(columnA,1)

Tags: mysql, union, temp-tables

Is there a way in MySql to use an either or in a select column.   For instance

```
select left(columnA,2) or right(columnA,1) as columnAlias, sum(columnB)
from table
where ((left(columnA,2) in ('aa','bb','cc')) or (right(columnA,1) in ('a,','b','c')))
group by columnAlias
```

what I have is a table where either the first 2 characters of the column or the last character of the column indicates the facility.  I need to sum the values by facility.   A union gets me part way there then I could loop through the resulting dataset and sum things up in the code (or do a stored proc to return the sums), but I am wondering if there is a way to just get it from the query.

I've tried using the union query as an on the fly temp table and doing the select and group on that but if there are no records returned from either of the select statments then it throws a "column columnA cannot be null error.

Also tried with the syntax above, but not getting the results I am expecting.  Any other ways to do this through the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a CASE would prob be your best bet here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html